# Typescript, Generics - omit null/undefined properties from a type

Tags: typescript, generics

I've tried to write a type in TypeScript which excludes null and undefined from a type:

`type NonNull<T> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends undefined | null ? never : T[P]; }`

From what I understand it should remove null or undefined properties from the type T.
However, when I try to use it:

`let test2: NonNull<{a: null, b: number}> = { b: 12 }`

It throws an error:

`Property 'a' is missing in type '{ b: number; }' but required in type 'NonNull<{ a: null; b: number; }>'`

Why the typescript compiler is complaining about a missing property 'a', when it should actually be excluded from the type ( as I declare 'a' as null in generic template)`?
If I am understanding the construction incorrectly, what does it actually do ?

as explained in above code.

Comment: I don't know what tutorial it's from, but `NonNull<T>` doesn't do anything good.  It maps the `a` property to the impossible `never` type; there are no values of that type so you can't set a   valid `a` property and thus you can't make a valid `NonNull<{a: null, b: number}>` object.  Not sure why the tutorial would write that, since it doesn't even filter unions.  It's just plain unhelpful.  There are ways to do what you're trying to do but that's out of scope for the question as asked.  Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz thanks for such a quick answer. I don't have access to that tutorial anymore. Maybe I just miswrote something or misunderstood. So could you write an generic type which achieves what I am trying to do so remove null and undefined properties ?

Comment: You miswrote it?  Then what's the question?  If the question is "how can I write a type function that omits null/undefined properties from a type" then can you [edit] the post to explicitly ask that instead of "what does this possibly mis-remembered thing do"?  (And then I could possibly answer with [this code](https://tsplay.dev/w6xV6m) if it meets your needs)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @jcalz I've fixed the post title based on your recommendation. You can now post the answer I think. Thank for the explanation. Sorry for not replying for so long.

Comment: Okay I've looked at it again and posted an answer; could you please [edit] the question itself and not just the title?  Or I would be happy to do it if you would prefer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to omit property keys from a type `T` in a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html), of the form `{[P in 〈 〉]: 〈 〉}` then you need to actually suppress them on the key side, not the value side.  If you're only checking `T[P] extends undefined | null` on the value side, then you won't be able to suppress the property.

Okay, so we want to omit keys where the property values are either `null` or `undefined`.  One way you can do it is to use [key remapping in mapped types via `as`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#key-remapping-in-mapped-types).  If you remap a key to `never`, the key is omitted from the mapped type output.  It looks like this:

```
type NonNull<T> = {
    [P in keyof T as T[P] extends undefined | null ? never : P]: T[P]
}

type Test = NonNull<{ a: null, b: number }>;
/* type Test = { b: number; }*/
```

And you can see it works as desired.

---

Note that this isn't how [the `Omit<T, K>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) works, partly because key remapping didn't exist when that type was introduced.  `Omit` looks like

```
type Omit<T, K extends string | number | symbol> = 
  { [P in Exclude<keyof T, K>]: T[P]; }
```

Using key remapping is easy because it lets us decide whether or not to keep a key `P` by looking at `T[P]` directly.  If you had to write a version that would work without remapping, it would be more complicated, since first we'd have to identify the keys to omit:

```
type NullableKeys<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]-?: T[P] extends undefined | null ? P : never
}[keyof T]
```

and then pass them to `Omit` or an equivalent:

```
type NonNull<T> = Omit<T, NullableKeys<T>>

type Test = NonNull<{ a: null, b: number }>;
/* type Test = { b: number; }*/
```

You can see that this also works.  In both cases, the `T[P] extends undefined | null` ends up taking effect on the key side of the mapped type and not the value side.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&module=7&suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors=false&pretty=true&ts=5.0.4&experimentalDecorators=false#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAlCYQyQbwFBIKQBcBPGZAOQHtgKBXAGwYB4AVAPiQF4d9D+A2gAUkAS2BIA1hBJUAZklZIQURcIC6SCAA8iEYABNVdQxDniIBpAB8kwRgyQB+OxABuEAE5IAXEiHqfqwafAQAvrihxGTIrNBE3EjUtA7M2Mp+9kwANEgARpl0YHleSGHsANxRAPQAVNHkivGJ6QV2RSWeFWW11ZG4EbigkLAIyADqokQAFlR0RGgYMDDiAOa8UaSN9EwgeQwQANIyUGycPHj8giLiUjLyiuoAtE5BGlq6+kZIJgZmFlZbFlHC4RJl3F4omEBNJZApWOpIvwtpQaDsWBxEgB5MBTNi5dF7A7HEinDjsJGEFFNKAJHjJdFpDLtHL5QrFUrlKr8OoNWLNC5s9ocro9PqRMJAA)